set face for text in izones
I'm trying to roll my own version of multiple-cursors using zones, and I'm currently a bit stuck at actually displaying the zones on the screen. I can easily set a zone as my current region by setting point and mark to the zone bounds, but I can't seem to reliably render the other zones.
So far, I've tried using highlight (since the zones docs mention it), but it achieves a different goal to what I think I need. This seems to make a persistent change to the text face in an area, whereas I'm wanting something that changes the face of text in the current zones, and updates as the zones are updated (much like the active region is highlighted).
As a workaround, I'm calling hlt-highlight-regions initially to show zones, then hlt-unhighlight-regions whenever I'm about to change the location of a zone, and hlt-highlight-regions afterward. This feels like a hack, it seems too complicated for what I'm trying to achieve, and sometimes highlighting is not removed from an area that a zone is longer covering.
Please let me know if you have suggestions for how to achieve this! I'm fairly new to emacs so I would be unsurprised if there's something straightforward that I've missed.

Something like this should do what your refresh-izones does.  IOW, you'd call foo after any operation that updates the set of zones.
(defun foo (face)
  (zz-zones-to-overlays
    (zz-map-zones (apply-partially #'toto face) (zz-basic-zones zz-izones))))

(defun toto (face izone) (append izone `((:zz-overlay face ,face))))

(You can simplify/enhance etc. -- e.g., update the :zz-overlay part of the zones' EXTRA portion, instead of just appending it each time.)

Looks like this only ever adds to the overlays (like show-izones), rather than clearing and adding (like replace-izones). That is, shrinking a zone then calling foo does not shrink or replace the corresponding overlay. But, I can still use your implementation in the same way I use show-izones, i.e. as part of replace-izones. Thanks

While researching to ask this question, I managed to answer it. Looking into the code for multiple-cursors, I noticed they use overlays to show the cursors. I didn't figure out how to properly use zz-zone-to-overlay, but some quick experimentation led me to this solution:
(defun show-zones (zones face)
  "add an overlay named `cursor' for each of `zones', using the provided `face' (`region' if called interactively)"
  (dolist (zone zones)
    (let* ((ov (make-overlay (car zone) (cadr zone))))
      (overlay-put ov 'face face)
      (overlay-put ov 'name 'cursor))))

(defun hide-zones ()
  "delete each overlay named `cursor'"
  (interactive)
  (remove-overlays nil nil 'name 'cursor))

(defun show-izones (izones face)
  "add an overlay named `cursor' for each of `zones', using the `region' face"
  (interactive `(,zz-izones region))
  (show-zones (zz-basic-zones izones) face))

(defun hide-izones ()
  "delete each overlay named `cursor'. identical to `hide-zones', provided for symmetry"
  (interactive)
  (hide-zones))

(defun refresh-zones (zones face)
  "delete each overlay named `cursor', then create one for each of `zones', using the provided `face'"
  (hide-zones)
  (show-zones zones face))

(defun refresh-izones (izones face)
  "delete each overlay named `cursor', then create one for each of `zones', using the provided `face' (`region' if called interactively)"
  (interactive `(,zz-izones region))
  (hide-izones)
  (show-izones izones face))

Now I simply call (refresh-izones zz-izones) after any operation that updates a zone position.
